# Are the elements of $C^\infty(M)$ smooth functions or equivalence classes of functions?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am familiar with the notation $C^\infty_p(M)$, which denotes the algebra of germs of $C^\infty$ functions at $p$, where two functions defined on a neighborhood of $p$ are equivalent if they agree on some, possible smaller neighborhood of $p$.

On wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics)#Examples
it is stated that $C^\infty(M)$ is the space of germs of smooth functions defined on the entirety of $M$. I'm a bit confused by this, because I don't see what the equivalence relation would be. Lee's smooth manifolds makes no such claim, it just says $C^\infty(M)$ is the algebra of smooth functions.

My question is are the elements of $C^\infty(M)$ usually taken to be smooth functions, or germs of smooth functions? And if they are germs, under what equivalence relation?

Edit: I was very likely misreading the wikipedia page.

Comment: Hi @bxw! $C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$ (almost always) denotes the space of smooth real (or complex) valued functions on $M$. (I didn't see the germ definition you mentioned in the section of the Wikipedia article you linked though.)

Comment: There are situations (e.g., working with bundle-valued cohomology) where it might be convenient to view $C^\infty(M)$ as a sheaf, but if I saw "$C^\infty(M)$" in the wild with no explanation I'd assume it denoted the algebra of functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: The elements of $C^\infty(M)$ are smooth functions from $M$ to $\mathbb R$; there is no equivalence relation involved.

I think you're misreading the Wikipedia article. It doesn't say "$C^\infty(M)$ is the space of germs of smooth functions defined on the entirety of $M$." What it actually says (with some irrelevant intervening text deleted) is

> the subset $C^{\infty }(X,Y)$ ... of smooth functions ... can be defined, and then spaces of germs of ... smooth ... functions can be constructed.

In the special case that $X$ is a smooth manifold and $Y=\mathbb R$, what this means is that for each open subset $U\subseteq X$, we define $C^\infty(U)$ to mean the set of smooth functions from $U$ to $\mathbb R$, and then for each $x\in M$, we use the equivalence relation described earlier in the article to construct the space $C^\infty_x$ of germs of smooth functions at $x$.

Comment: Hi professor, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4112007/find-the-centroid-of-a-symmetric-compact-manifold), please? It is some time I am trying to prove this without success.